# How to simplify java code with power of ten?

Tags: java, long-integer

Given the java code:

```
private Collection<String> xxx(Collection<String> values) {
    List<String> valuesMutable = new ArrayList<>(values);
    String origValues = valuesMutable.get(0);
    if (!origValues.endsWith("000000")) {
      valuesMutable.set(0, String.valueOf((Long.parseLong(origValues)) * 1000000));
    }
    return valuesMutable;
  }
```

I am thinking about the somehow duplictate information of the `endsWith("000000")` and the `1000000`:
is there an easy way to interlock the power of ten?

Comment: What's the point in converting the String to a long just to append "000000"?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want something like `java.math.BigDecimal.pow`?

`new BigDecimal(origValues).multiply(new BigDecimal(10).pow(6))`